# Why HttpHeaders doent send Bareer token in POST Request?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am using this in my service:

```
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
```

and I'm triying to do a Post with this :

```
 public sendInvitation(id):Observable<any>{
    let url = URL_SERVICIOS + '/users/contacts?id=' + id;
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.getToken());
    return  this.http
      .post(url , headers)
      .map(res => {
        return res['result'];
      })
      .catch(this.handleError)
  }
```

But when i am debugging i look : 
1.OPTIONS REQUEST with 200 OK

[image]

2. POST WITH 401 , because TOKEN DOESNT SEND

[image]

I've tried to change:

`.appened` with `.set` but this doesn't function yet

Maybe I am losing anything?

It's strange because when I do GET, it does function well

```
  public listContacts(type):Observable<Invitation[]>{
    let url = URL_SERVICIOS + '/users/contacts?type=' + type;
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization','Bearer ' +this.getToken());
    return  this.http
      .get(url , {headers})
      .map(res => {
        return res['result'];
      })
      .catch(this.handleError)
  }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: did you try `.set` from `sendInvitation()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should fix the error:

```
public sendInvitation(id):Observable<any>{
  let url = URL_SERVICIOS + '/users/contacts?id=' + id;
  let headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.getToken());
  return  this.http
    .post(url , {}, {headers: headers})
    .map(res => {
      return res['result'];
    })
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a conflict in the parameters you used in the Post method.

you use the Post method as follows:

```
  .post(url , headers)
```

but the actual parameters is

```
 .post(url, body, headers)
```

you need to specify the body, in order to deliver the headers as it suppose to be.